# MySQL Get All Records for the next week

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to get all of the records in my database for the next week.

Here is the query I'm using, but it's producing 0 results

```
SELECT * FROM snip WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(init_visit_start)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
```

Here is a small data example:

[image]

Comment: None of your sample data is in the next week. You should also test the year, otherwise you'll get rows from other years that are in the same week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[YEARWEEK](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-yearweek-function.php)**

```
SELECT * FROM snip WHERE YEARWEEK(init_visit_start) = YEARWEEK(NOW()) + 1;
```